# Trigger Hook with db.command

Tags: orientdb

```
  public class Hooks {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        ODatabaseDocument db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/New");
        MyHook hook = new MyHook();

        try {
           db.open("admin", "admin");
           db.registerHook(hook);
           db.command(new OCommandSQL("create class Account")).execute();

           db.getMetadata().getSchema().reload();

           ODocument accountR = new ODocument("Account");
           accountR.field("type", "facebook");
           accountR.save();

           db.command(new OCommandSQL("insert into Account set type = 'twitter'")).execute();

        } finally {
           db.unregisterHook(hook);
           db.close();
        }
     }

     private static class MyHook extends ODocumentHookAbstract {

        public MyHook() {
           setIncludeClasses("Account");
        }

        @Override
        public ORecordHook.DISTRIBUTED_EXECUTION_MODE getDistributedExecutionMode() {
           return ORecordHook.DISTRIBUTED_EXECUTION_MODE.SOURCE_NODE;
        }

        @Override
        public ORecordHook.RESULT onRecordBeforeCreate(ODocument iDocument) {
           System.out.println("before create : " + iDocument.field("type"));
           return ORecordHook.RESULT.RECORD_NOT_CHANGED;
        }
     }
  }
```

The output is:

```
before create : facebook
```

This means that the hook was only triggered in doc.save().

Is there a way to also trigger it with db.command(...) ?

(I have the same problem when trying to delete. Only doc.delete() will trigger the hook)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OCommandSQL` command is executed by the sever. If you use a `plocal` connection you will see that it works as you expected.
To execute a (java) hook server side, it has to be registered there, see [documentation](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Java-Hooks.html). Also note you can use [Dynamic Hooks](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Dynamic-Hooks.html).

BTW Welcome at stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ahah. Thank you Ronald.